# show that $ \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=C(b-a)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $f(x)=C$ be a constant function on the interval $[a,b]$; and let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$.

With some help I have calculated $L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$ and got the following,

As $f$ is constant, $\sup_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)=\inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)=c$

Since $\sum_{i=1}^n\Delta x_i=b-a$, we get:

$$L(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^nm_i\Delta x_i = c(b-a)=\sum_{i=1}^nM_i\Delta x_i=U(f,P)$$

So my first question is, is $f$ Riemann integrable.

My thoughts are, using the definition we have been given in class, $f$ is Riemann intergrable if $L(f)=U(f)$ with $L(f)$ being the lower sum, and $U(f)$ being the upper sum.

So clearly from my work above $f$ Riemann integrable.

But then how do I show that $$ \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=C(b-a)$$

Comment: Observe that $L(f)$ is the limit, when the mesh of the partition tends to zero, of $L(f,P)$.The same for $U(f)$ and $U(f,P)$. You had not shown something about the limit of these sums.

Comment: no. Take a book and study the topic in depth. This is very well shown in any introductory book of real analysis. It is very clear that your knowledge about the matter is very insufficient, answering here will not help you at all. You need study the theory about the Riemann integration first to know, at least, the basic concepts. After come here again to get help about any doubt you had.

Comment: yes I do need to review this topic, thanks for the tips

Comment: @jh123 What do you know about $L(f)$ and $U(f)$ in relations to $L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$? What if we make a refinement $P_1$ of $P$, how will that effect $L(f,P_1)$ and $U(f,P_1)$? What is it's relationship to $L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$?

Comment: not well enough to prove this answer

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x) = C:

$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{\rho->0}\sum f(x) \Delta x = \lim_{\rho->0}\sum C \Delta x = C \lim_{\rho->0}\sum  \Delta x = C(b-a)$

Comment: why is that equal to the lim p->0?

Comment: the point is that you can take const outside of the sum and limit

Answer (score 0):

HINT: the mesh $\Delta$ of a partition $P$ is the maximum length of it sub-intervals, that is, if

$$P:=\{a=x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n=b\}$$

is a partition of the interval $[a,b]$ then the mesh of $P$ is defined as

$$\Delta(P):=\max\{x_{i+1}-x_i: x_i,x_{i+1}\in P\}$$

A integral of Riemann can be defined through the notions of upper sums and lower sums, that is, we first define the upper integral and the lower integral of $f$ in $[a,b]$ as the limits

$$U(f):=\lim_{n\to \infty} U(f,P_n),\quad\text{and}\quad L(f):=\lim_{n\to \infty}L(f,P_n)$$

where the $P_n$ represent any sequence of partitions of $[a,b]$ such that it mesh tends to zero, that is

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Delta(P_n)=0$$

Then if $U(f)=L(f)$ we can define the integral of Riemann as

$$\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm dx:=U(f)=L(f)$$

---

A way to define a sequence of partitions $P_n$ with it mesh converging to zero is

$$P_n:=\left\{x_i:=a+i\cdot\frac{b-a}{n}:i=0,1,\ldots,n\right\}$$

Then observe that

$$\Delta(P_n)=\max\left\{a+(i+1)\frac{b-a}n-\left(a+i\cdot\frac{b-a}n\right):i=0,1,\ldots,n\right\}=\frac{b-a}n$$

Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Delta(P_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}n=0$. Then we can define

$$U(f)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sup_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)\right)(x_i-x_{i-1})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}n\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n\sup_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)$$

and

$$L(f)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)\right)(x_i-x_{i-1})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}n\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n\inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)$$

---

From above, you can solve the exercise easily. Anyway the best thing you can do, as I said in a comment, is sit down and study in depth the theory of the integral of Riemann.

There are many slightly different ways (and using different notations) to present the theory of the integral of Riemann so what I had written above could not fit whatever you see about this topic.