# prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum

Considering the function $f$ defined on $[0,1]$ by

$$ { f }(x)=\begin{cases} 0\quad ,\quad x \in [0,1)  \\ 1\quad ,\quad x=1\end{cases} $$

I need to prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$

So,

Let $\epsilon>0.$ Let $P_{\epsilon}$ be a partition of the interval $[0,1]$ where $P_{\epsilon}=\{[0,1-2\epsilon], [1-2\epsilon,1-\epsilon],[1-\epsilon,1]\}$ for some fixed $0<\epsilon<1$

And I know that,

$$U(f,P) = \sum_{[x_i,x_{i+1}] \in P} (x_{i+1} - x_i) \sup_{[x_{i+1},x_i]} f(x)$$

$$
L(f,P) = \sum_{[x_i,x_{i+1}] \in P} (x_{i+1} - x_i) \inf_{[x_{i+1},x_i]} f(x)
$$

Then how can I show that $L(f,P)=U(f,P)$ which would mean it would be Riemann integrable.

Comment: You cannot shows that $U(f,P)=L(f,P)$ because they are differents, no matter what partition you use. What you must show is that $U(f)=L(f)$. Take a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212275/show-that-int-abfxdx-cb-a/2212412#2212412).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a fairly easy result that the Riemann Integral exists if $U(f,P) - L(f,P) = \epsilon$ for some Partition, $P$

Also, note that My upper sum here must be $\epsilon$:

$\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\sum_{[x_{i},x_{i+1}]} (x_{i + 1} - x_{i}) \sup_{[x_{i},x_{i+1}]} f(x) &= \big((1 - 2\epsilon) - 0)\cdot 0 + \big((1 - \epsilon) - (1 - 2\epsilon)\big)\cdot 0 + \big((1-(1 - \epsilon)\big)\cdot 1 \\ &= 0 + 0 + (\epsilon)\cdot 1 \\ &= \epsilon
\end{split}
\end{equation*}$
because we are taking the supremum of $f(x)$ in ***each*** subinterval, but $f(x)$ is uniformly zero for all points in my first two subintervals.

Pretty clearly my lower sum must be $0$, and so $U(f,P) - L(f,P) = \epsilon - 0 = \epsilon$

Comment: what partition have you chosen?

Comment: and why is the lower sum 0?

Comment: @fr14 you had been answered about why $L(f,P)=0$ [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213554/a-question-in-real-analysis).

Comment: @fr14 I used the partition you gave in your setup

Comment: @j.mac so $$U(f,P) = \sum_{[x_i,x_{i+1}] \in P} (x_{i+1} - x_i) \sup_{[x_{i+1},x_i]} f(x) =  1 - (1 - \epsilon) = \epsilon.$$???

Comment: @fr14 see edit above, I ran out of room here

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f_n=0$  and $g_n$ whose restriction on $[0,1-1/n]$ is zero and whose restriction on $[1-1/n,1]$ is $1+1/n$, $f_n\leq f\leq g_n$ and $\mu(g_n-f_n)\leq {1\over{n}}$.

Comment: how do I use that to solve my problem?

Comment: This shows the integral of $f$ is zero since $f_n$ and $g_n$ are simple function.

Comment: This is pretty much a Lebesgue approach to the problem, which is not appropriate in this situation.